# Why does a cat-5 cross cable work when connected between my computer and my switch?

Tags: lan, switch, cable

By accident I've used a cross LAN cable to connect my computer with my switch, and I was very surprised that it worked. On the early days of LAN, this did not work. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is able to be done because of the handy feature called *Automatic Medium-Dependent Interface Crossover* aka Auto-MDIX. When Auto-MDIX is enabled on an interface, the interface automatically detects the required cable connection type (straight through or crossover) and configures the connection appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Newer (that is, non-ancient) ethernet hardware figures automatically out if the cable is crossed or not, and acts accordingly.